# Collision Detection not working in Snake Game

Tags: java, collision-detection, game-physics

I've been writing a snake game (the retro arcade one) and while implementing the collision detection, I realized that it didn't even work at all. This isn't first time I've had to use collision detection so I don't think the problem lies there (but it could!). Rather, I think it has to do with the outside classes and something about the coordinates not updating, but it could also just be something else. Here is the code:

NOTE: This isn't the full code, but to avoid confusion... here is a list of all the classes (and yes I know, there's a lot... but I like to be organized)

Main
View
Model
MoveAction
Entity (Interface)
Food
Segment
Snake
Direction (ENUM)

Model

```
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Model {
    List<Entity> entities;
    List<Direction> direction;
    Snake snake;
    Segment snakeHead;
    Food food;
    View view;
    int timeSpent = 0;

    public Model() {
        entities = new ArrayList<Entity>(3);
        direction = new ArrayList<Direction>();
        direction.add(Direction.RIGHT);
        snake = new Snake(new Point(100, 100));
        food = new Food(new Point(300, 200));
        entities.add(snake);
        entities.add(food);

        Timer timer = new Timer(5, new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                update();
                view.repaint();
            }
        });
        timer.start();
    }

    public void update() {
        Segment snakeHead = snake.getSegments()[0];
        changeHeadLoc(snakeHead);
        changeSegmentLoc();

    }

    public void checkFoodCol(Segment snakeHead) {
        if (snakeHead.getLocation().x + snakeHead.getSize().width > food.getLocation().x) {
            System.out.println("1");
            // snake.increaseSegmentCount(1);
        }
        if (snakeHead.getLocation().x < food.getLocation().x + food.getSize().width) {
            System.out.println("2");
            // snake.increaseSegmentCount(2);
        }
        if (snakeHead.getLocation().y + snakeHead.getSize().height > food.getLocation().y) {
            System.out.println("3");
            // snake.increaseSegmentCount(3);
        }
        if (snakeHead.getLocation().y < food.getLocation().y + food.getSize().height) {
            System.out.println("4");
            // snake.increaseSegmentCount(4);
        }
    }

    public void changeHeadLoc(Segment snakeHead) {
        if (direction.contains(Direction.UP)) {
            snakeHead.setLocation(new Point(snakeHead.getLocation().x, snakeHead.getLocation().y - 1));
        }
        if (direction.contains(Direction.DOWN)) {
            snakeHead.setLocation(new Point(snakeHead.getLocation().x, snakeHead.getLocation().y + 1));
        }
        if (direction.contains(Direction.LEFT)) {
            snakeHead.setLocation(new Point(snakeHead.getLocation().x - 1, snakeHead.getLocation().y));
        }
        if (direction.contains(Direction.RIGHT)) {
            snakeHead.setLocation(new Point(snakeHead.getLocation().x + 1, snakeHead.getLocation().y));

        }
    }

    public void changeSegmentLoc() {
        if (!direction.isEmpty()) {
            for (int i = 1; i <= snake.getSegmentCount(); i++) {
                Segment currentSegment = snake.getSegments()[i];
                Segment previousSegment = snake.getSegments()[i - 1];
                if (currentSegment != null) {
                    if (direction.contains(Direction.UP)) {
                        currentSegment.setLocation(
                                new Point(previousSegment.getLocation().x, previousSegment.getLocation().y - 1));
                    }
                    if (direction.contains(Direction.DOWN)) {
                        currentSegment.setLocation(
                                new Point(previousSegment.getLocation().x, previousSegment.getLocation().y + 1));
                    }
                    if (direction.contains(Direction.LEFT)) {
                        currentSegment.setLocation(
                                new Point(previousSegment.getLocation().x - 1, previousSegment.getLocation().y));
                    }
                    if (direction.contains(Direction.RIGHT)) {
                        currentSegment.setLocation(
                                new Point(previousSegment.getLocation().x + 1, previousSegment.getLocation().y));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public Entity[] getEntities() {
        return entities.toArray(new Entity[0]);
    }

    public List<Direction> getDirection() {
        return direction;
    }

    public void setView(View view) {
        this.view = view;
    }
}
```

Food

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Point;

public class Food implements Entity {
    Point location;
    Dimension size = new Dimension(15, 15);

    public Food(Point location) {
        this.location = location;
    }

    public Dimension getSize() {
        return size;
    }

    public Point getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.fillRect(getLocation().x, getLocation().y, getSize().width, getSize().height);
    }
}
```

Segment

```
    import java.awt.Color;
    import java.awt.Dimension;
    import java.awt.Graphics;
    import java.awt.Point;

    public class Segment {
        Point location;
        Point oldLocation;

        public Segment(Point location) {
            this.location = location;
        }

        public Dimension getSize() {
            return new Dimension(20, 20);
        }

        public void setLocation(Point location) {
            oldLocation = location;
            this.location = location;
        }

        public Point getLocation() {
            return location;
        }

        public Point getOldLocation() {
            return oldLocation;
        }

        public void paint(Graphics g) {
            g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            g.fillRect(location.x, location.y, 20, 20);
        }
    }

Snake
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Point;

public class Snake implements Entity {
    Point location;
    Segment[] segments;
    int segmentCount = 0;

    public Snake(Point location) {
        this.location = location;
        segments = new Segment[25];
        segments[segmentCount] = new Segment(new Point(location.x, location.y));

        segmentCount++;
    }

    public void increaseSegmentCount(int relativeTo) {
        // TODO Add code to make it add the new Segment correctly

        segments[segmentCount] = new Segment(
                new Point(segments[segmentCount - 1].getLocation().x + segments[segmentCount - 1].getSize().width,
                        segments[segmentCount - 1].getLocation().y + segments[segmentCount - 1].getSize().height));

        if (relativeTo == 1) {

        }

        segmentCount++;

    }

    public Segment[] getSegments() {
        return segments;
    }

    public int getSegmentCount() {
        return segmentCount;
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        for (Segment segment : segments) {
            if (segment != null) {
                segment.paint(g);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see any code that calls checkFoodCol above. Should that be in your update method?

Comment: Omg... How could I have missed that? I'm sorry for wasting your time, I'm still a novice programmer so this sort of thing happens a lot.

Comment: No problem. Added as an answer. Glad to be of assistance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call your checkFoodCol method inside your update method somewhere e.g.

```
public void update() {
    Segment snakeHead = snake.getSegments()[0];
    checkFoodCol(snakeHead);
    changeHeadLoc(snakeHead);
    changeSegmentLoc();
}
```